# Does SVMlight output the classification scores?

Tags: classification, svm, document-classification

I need to know if SVMlight outputs classification scores. I couldn't find it anywhere.I know that for example libSVM does.thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVMLight's output consists of a "prediced value" for each classified instance. Strictly speaking, this is not a "classification score",  but can be used as some measure of certainty.

There are many methods of transforming this into some type of probability measure (I guess this is what you're referring to in 'scores'). For instance, see [a paper by JS Platt on the topic](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jplatt/SVMprob.ps.gz)